# How to better setup fetch with useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

Im learning JS and React and I came to the code example below and some parts I don't understand properly. The second .then is inside useUffect is this ok, or it's better to be in getData func? Also in render there is data**?**.map and I don't understand why we need ?, is this ternary operator? Is so I thought that ternary operator requires : as a second parameter. Thanks in advance!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const FetchData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const fetchURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
    
    const getData = () => fetch(`${fetchURL}/posts`)
        .then((res) => res.json());

    useEffect(() => {
        getData().then((data) => setData(data));
    }, []);

    return (<div>
        {data?.map(item => (
            <ul>
                <li>{item.title}</li>
          </ul>
      ))}
  </div>);
};

export default FetchData;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, your code is fine, Move `getData and fetchURL` into `useEffect` incase if there's any error.

Also, You can simply use `async/await` approach for the same.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const FetchData = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null) // here you can define `[]` if you don't want to check `?`
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";
    const getData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(`${fetchURL}/posts`)
      const result = await res.json();
      setData(result);
    }
    getData()

  }, []);

    return (<div>
        {data?.map(item => (
            <ul>
                <li>{item.title}</li>
          </ul>
      ))}
  </div>);
};

export default FetchData;
```

`?` is Called [Optional Chain Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), which will help you to check whether the value is nullish `(null or undefined)`.

Basically, it just doing `if (data) { data.map...}`

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the ?. So it's always better to do async/await for fetching data?

Comment: Nothing like that, I just another way of doing and looks much more readable